# nginx mutiple location for wordpress and laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx

I want to setting wordpress is hold base domain (/), laravel directory just catch 3 sub-location (start with: su-panel|su-admin|su-resources). This is my setting:

```
server {

    listen 8002 default_server;
    listen [::]:8002 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;
    root /Users/phann123/Documents/projects/we-ac-blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location ~ ^/(node|socket\.io) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ ^/(su-panel|su-admin) {
        root /Users/phann123/Documents/projects/web-acc/public/;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string =404;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =403;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

But when i enter : http://localhost:8002/su-panel/login, alway see 404 page nginx. What wrong with me ?

Comment: What is the full path of the file `index.php` file which handles the `/su-panel/login` URI?

Comment: /Users/phann123/Documents/projects/web-acc/public/index.php   this is full path

Comment: Are there any resource files (js,css,img) under `/Users/phann123/Documents/projects/web-acc/public/` which are accessed by URI, or is it only `index.php`?

Comment: any my friend :D

Comment: I am trying to understand the directory structure under `/Users/phann123/Documents/projects/web-acc/public/` and how it relates to the `/su-panel/xxx` and `/su-admin/xxx` URIs.

Comment: do you know laravel ?

Comment: I do not - I know Nginx and Wordpress.